# How to count non-empty lines inside a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, match

i'm using this function to count empty lines inside a string.

```
function count_empty_lines(text){
    return text ? (text.match(/^[ \t]*$/gm) || []).length : 0;
}
```

I'm trying to edit that regex in order to implement a function that counts **non** empty lines.

```
function count_non_empty_lines(text){
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
text = ["  a", "b", "", "c", "", "", "   d  "].join("\n")

cnt = (text.match(/^\s*\S/gm) || "").length
alert(cnt)
```

Comment: Why a simple `^.*?\S` will do the job. Note that `\s` matches newline characters also.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply `.split("\n").length` to get the number of all lines and subtract your existing result from that:

```
function count_non_empty_lines(text){
    return text.split("\n").length - count_empty_lines(text);
}
```

Comment: of course, but that would not be the most efficient way to achieve that.

Comment: No, but it *is* the simplest

Comment: Since I'll be processing lots of strings I need the most efficient and fast way to retrieve the data. @georg 's answer seems to be the best approach. Thanks anyways!